# Writing to CSV file with multiline

Tags: java, csv

I am basically trying to write to a csv file, one of the cells in that csv file will contain multiple lines but one cell. I have read online that if you wrap it around "" you will generally be fine. This is the case in finder, however when I try to open it in excel it does not work that way what is your suggestion

Comment: It would be easier to help you fix/finish your code if you post what you have written so far.

Comment: You are right about the quotes; this is defined in section 2.6 of [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#section-2). What does Excel do? What is the expected way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this tutorial.

https://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-csv

But, post your code to more detailed response